# Official Dart Polymer samples not displaying in Chrome (work in IE)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

https://www.dartlang.org/samples/

I have the latest version of Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m

None of the polymer samples work in the browser, I just get a blank box where the sample should display.

I tried on IE and Firefox, 4 of 6 samples work fine (none work on Chrome).

- <strike>Defining a custom element</strike> - *broken*
- Searchable List
- Get input from a form
- TodoMVC
- <strike>Polymer and internationalization</strike> - *broken*
- A task management tool

Is there something I need to do to get them working?

Background - I want to develop the equivalent of a desktop application that I can run in the browser as a learning experience and try to use a widget UI library.

Comment: I guess it's a problem with the polyfills. What imports do you have on the entry page? What Polymer version are you using?

Comment: For me all the examples are working. Do they require this flag to be enabled: 

chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

?

Comment: Do you run the samples from a web server?

Comment: I was running the samples from the dartlang.org link. I will try setting the flag when I get home. Chrome is not available at work.

Comment: I tried enabling the experimental features but the samples still do not work. For example, the Todo MVC is just a gray box.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you should need to do for these to work. They all work for me in latest (stock) stable Chrome without any adjustments (`36.0.1985.143 (Official Build 287914) m`).

I would check the console for errors (press `F12` to open the dev tools), and also try in Incognito Mode (which should disable most/all extensions) to see if there are any clues.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again with the latest build.